# SP 2010 constantly says 'A backup or restore is currently in progress' & it never runs!

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, backup

We're running SP 2010 & I am able to click on Farm Backup & Restore and or Granular Backup but they'll both just sit there all day saying SP 2010 'A backup or restore is currently in progress' & it never actually seems to run! Nothing appears in the share.

I do get an warning in Event Viewer;

> The start address
>   sts4:///contentdbid={e9c90e88-9cec-4d3c-bea1-131fd443bad8}
>   cannot be crawled.
>
> Context: Application 'Search_index_file_on_the_search_server', Catalog
>   'Search'
>
> Details:  The SharePoint server was moved to a different location.
>   (0x8004fd12)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This Search Error is not related to the backup as far i know. 
couple of thing to check and make sure.

**For Backup**

- Go to Central admin > Monotroing > Timer Job Status...on this page see if you can find a running backup/retore job, Cancel that one and then perform the backup again.

**For Search.**
Looks like your crawler unable to reach the WFE. To fix this, you have to make the HOST file entries.

- Login to the server hosting the crawl component.
- Make an entry in the host file for the URL pointing to one of the
  WFEs **Note:** Bypassing the loadbalancing device
- Try to browse the site and check if in the address bar the URL of the
  site gets appended with the querystring “
  ?aspxautodetectcookiesupport=1” and in subsequent browsing of the
  site you don’t see this query string.
- Check the session state setting for the website in IIS, set session
  state mode to In process and Cookie Mode to “Use Cookies”

Check this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/yashgoel-msft/archive/2012/03/14/crawl-fails-with-quot-the-sharepoint-server-was-moved-to-a-different-location-quot.aspx

Comment: Thank you for you input & help, my main concern is trying to get the backup to run, I tried deleting it & running it again but it just does the same  every time. Is there anything else I can try? I've set the permissions to the share etc.

Comment: did you restart the timer service on the server, if possible reboot them?

Comment: Hi, yes I did thanks, but the same thing. I've now used the PShell & it appears to have worked, so thanks to everyone for your input.